# Is there a possibility to have a web ssh interface?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

is there a way to make a web interface for ssh on Ubuntu?

Something like Digital ocean's method is what we are currently in need of.

Answer (score 1):

[Yes.](http://wiki.kartbuilding.net/index.php/Ajaxterm)

(padding padding padding padding)